# JavaScript object like String literal doesn't to set property

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript everything is object like String literal, numbers, Object...
And properties can be added to objects dynamically also, but I am adding property to object which refer to string then it seems it is not working
Following is JS code which I am running

```
var aVar = "some string";
console.log(aVar);
aVar.name = 'raj';
console.log(aVar.name);
```

Output...

hi
some string
undefined

Comment: @ShanerM13 you're thinking of HTML, this question has nothing to do with HTML

Comment: You've declared a `string` primative, which is not implemented as an object, like `var aVar = new String("some string");` would do.

Comment: This has to do with boxing - i didn't read the dupe links, but judging from the titles, they are about something else.

Comment: Long story short (and accordingly inaccurate, please research), if the javascript engine encounters a property access on a primitive, boxing occurs, aka the property access is performed on a temporary boxed object, in this case something similar to `new String('some string')`. This temporary object is lost after the assignment, so you cannot recover the set property.

Comment: Thank you @ScottMarcus  your answer is correct, I could verify it. Thanks again for clarification